# I am trying to retrieve results from two for each loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to retrieve the data from two for-each loops. Where I'm expecting it to get the data on same line or row.

```
int i=0,j=0;

System.out.println("First Elements out---");
for(Element ele1:els){
    System.out.println(els.get(i));
    i++;
}

System.out.println("Second Elements out---");
for(Element ele2:els){
    System.out.println(els.get(j));
    j++;
}
```

Actual result:

```
First Elements out---
Element_1_1
Element_1_2

Second Elements out---
Element_2_1
Element_2_2
```

Expected result:

```
Element_1_1 : Element_2_1 
Element_1_2 : Element_2_2
```

Comment: Use a standard loop with an index.

Comment: Agree, because elements `ele1` and `ele2` are never used, among other things.

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? It seems like you're iterating over the same `els` iterables twice, but your 'Actual result' shows that you're getting different elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop using index value. I am assuming that both the list/array has same number of elements for you to print they expected way.

Sample code :

```
//you need to get the length and you can directly use this in the loop
int number_of_elements = els_one.length(); 
for(int i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++){
    System.out.println(els_one.get(i)+" : "+els_two.get(i));                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` inside the loops to avoid printing newlines. You will want to add spaces after each item so they are properly spaced on each line, and you will want an empty `System.out.println();` call after each loop so that the two loops print on separate lines.

Comment: I want to combine both the results coming out from two for each loops.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both Elements have the same size, check the following code:

```
for (int i=0; i<els_1.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(els_1.get(i) + " : " + els_2.get(i));
}
```

Also it is assumed that Elements implement the size() method.

Note that if elements are not of the same size / length, then you should check for null pointers, etc.

Comment: One fix for the elements not being the same size is to modify the for loop to use `i < Math.min(els_1.size(), els_2.size());`. This will make it that any elements in the larger list will not be printed if the sizes differ.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = 0, i< els.size()-1; i+=2){
    System.out.println(els.get(i) + " : " + els.get(i + 1));
}`

Can see if above is what you are expecting? Although I think it's better to use a different data structure like 2D array/ HashMap depending on your use case.